# How to dynamically check if a Jquery variable has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am having is that nothing changes when the variable schmeckle goes over 49, the html doesn't update. (Line 13 in the code.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var schmeckle = 0;
    $('#schmeckleAdder').click(function() {
        $('#iAmTheBody').css("background-color", "orange");
        if (schmeckle == 0) {
            schmeckle = schmeckle + 1;
            $('#iAmTheBody').append('<p id="howManyYouGot">You have ' + schmeckle + ' schmeckles!</p>');
        }
        else {
            schmeckle = schmeckle + 1;
            $('#howManyYouGot').html('<p>You have ' + schmeckle + ' schmeckles!</p>');
        }
    });
    if (schmeckle > 49) {
        $('iAmTheBody').append('<button type="button" id="mortyBuyer">Buy a morty!</button>');
    }
    else {

    }
});
```

Comment: Your if schmeckle > 49 statement only runs once, on document ready.  Move it inside your click handler to get it to work the way you expect

Answer (score 0):

You missed the ID selector : change `$('iAmTheBody')` => `$('#iAmTheBody')` . And you should move your check inside the logic where you increase your counter: See
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/cwknnv5n/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var schmeckle = 0;
    $('#schmeckleAdder').click(function() {
        $('#iAmTheBody').css("background-color", "orange");
        if (schmeckle == 0) {
            schmeckle = schmeckle + 1;
            $('#iAmTheBody').append('<p id="howManyYouGot">You have ' + schmeckle + ' schmeckles!</p>');
        }
        else {
            schmeckle = schmeckle + 1;
            $('#howManyYouGot').html('<p>You have ' + schmeckle + ' schmeckles!</p>');
            if (schmeckle > 3) { //change to 49 as you wish
               $('#iAmTheBody').append('<button type="button" id="mortyBuyer">Buy a morty!</button>');
            } else { }
        }
    });
});
```